# How to give value to an array from input?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

i'm a total newbie to this.
I'd like to receive string in input the following:
Surname:
Name:
Country:
Region:
Email:
Phone number:
Special Requests:
Then I have to show them back in output when the button get pressed.
You can edit the code as much as you want because I think I made everything wrong.
The real problem is the output and the array.
What am I doing wrong (everything, I already know)?
Thanks.

```js
  var risposta;
var array = ["cognome", "nome", "comune", "regioni", "email", "telefono"]

      function soluzione()
      {
                for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                var a = input[i];
                k = k + "array[" + i + "].value= "
                                   + a.value + " ";
                                   
            }
          risposta = "Il numero è" +array+"  Dai un altro numero.";
          document.forms[1].risultato.value=risposta;
                setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload()}, 3000);
      }
```

```css
#elaborato{
    border-width:10px;
    background-color:#FFFDC6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
    <center><td>  <a href="http://www.istitutokennedy.net/">
         <img alt="Istituto Kennedy" src="logokennedy.png"
         width=400" height="120">
      </a>
            <td><h1>Form istituto Kennedy</h1></center>

   </head>
   <body bgcolor="#FFFDC6">
     <div>
         <table id="form" align="center">
            <tr>
               <br>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
              <form id="myForm" oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
                     Cognome: <INPUT type="text" style="padding-top:5px;" name="cognome" size=40><br><br>
                     Nome: <INPUT type="text" style="padding-top:5px;"name="nome" size=30><br><br>
                    Comune di Residenza: <INPUT type="text" style="padding-top:5px;"name="comune" size=12><br><br>
                      <label for="regioni">Regione:</label>
                        <select id="regioni" name="regioni">
                          <option value="Abruzzo">Abruzzo</option>
                          <option value="Basilicata">Basilicata</option>
                          <option value="Calabria">Calabria</option>
                          <option value="Campania">Campania</option>
                          <option value="Emilia-Romagna">Emilia-Romagna</option>
                          <option value="Friuli-Venezia Giulia">Friuli-Venezia Giulia</option>
                          <option value="Lazio">Lazio</option>
                          <option value="Liguria">Liguria</option>
                          <option value="Lombardia">Lombardia</option>
                          <option value="Marche">Marche</option>
                          <option value="Molise">Molise</option>
                          <option value="Piemonte">Piemonte</option>
                          <option value="Puglia">Puglia</option>
                          <option value="Sardegna">Sardegna</option>
                          <option value="Sicilia">Sicilia</option>
                          <option value="Toscana">Toscana</option>
                          <option value="Trentino-Alto Adige">Trentino-Alto Adige</option>
                          <option value="Umbria">Umbria</option>
                          <option value="Valle d Aosta">Valle d'Aosta</option>
                          <option value="Veneto">Veneto</option>
</select>
                Email: <INPUT type="text" style="padding-top:5px;"name="email" size=30><br><br>
                Telefono: <INPUT type="text" style="padding-top:5px;"name="telefono" size=15><br><br>

   <label> Richieste Particolari </label>
   <textarea rows="12" cols="60">

         </textarea>
<INPUT type="button" class="myButton" value="  Soluzione  " onClick="soluzione()"><br>
       </form>
       <form>

                    <br>Risultato: <INPUT type="text" style="padding-top:5px;" name="risultato" size=44><br>
                 </form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add a new input value to the array.

just use `array_name.push(value)`

For output use an iterator, like for loop or for each.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I could come up with is this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      Cognome: <input type="text" style="padding-top: 5px" name="cognome" size="40" /><br /><br />
      Nome: <input type="text" style="padding-top: 5px" name="nome" size="30" /><br /><br />
      Comune di Residenza: <input type="text" style="padding-top: 5px" name="comune" size="12" /><br /><br />
      <label for="regioni">Regione:</label>
      <select id="regioni" name="regioni">
        <option value="Abruzzo">Abruzzo</option>
        <option value="Basilicata">Basilicata</option>
        <option value="Calabria">Calabria</option>
        <option value="Campania">Campania</option>
        <option value="Emilia-Romagna">Emilia-Romagna</option>
        <option value="Friuli-Venezia Giulia">Friuli-Venezia Giulia</option>
        <option value="Lazio">Lazio</option>
        <option value="Liguria">Liguria</option>
        <option value="Lombardia">Lombardia</option>
        <option value="Marche">Marche</option>
        <option value="Molise">Molise</option>
        <option value="Piemonte">Piemonte</option>
        <option value="Puglia">Puglia</option>
        <option value="Sardegna">Sardegna</option>
        <option value="Sicilia">Sicilia</option>
        <option value="Toscana">Toscana</option>
        <option value="Trentino-Alto Adige">Trentino-Alto Adige</option>
        <option value="Umbria">Umbria</option>
        <option value="Valle d Aosta">Valle d'Aosta</option>
        <option value="Veneto">Veneto</option>
      </select>
      Email: <input type="text" style="padding-top: 5px" name="email" size="30" /><br /><br />
      Telefono: <input type="text" style="padding-top: 5px" name="telefono" size="15" /><br /><br />

      <label> Richieste Particolari </label>
      <textarea rows="12" cols="60"> </textarea>
      <input type="submit" class="myButton" value="Soluzione" /><br />
    </form>

    <br />Risultato:
    <pre name="risultato" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js" />
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
var risposta = {};
var array = ["cognome", "nome", "comune", "regioni", "email", "telefono"];

const formEl = document.getElementById("myForm");
formEl.addEventListener("submit", (e) => soluzione(e));

function soluzione(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let value = document.getElementsByName(array[i])[0].value;
    risposta[array[i]] = value;
  }
  document.getElementsByName("risultato")[0].innerHTML = JSON.stringify(risposta, null, 2);
}
```

If you can understand then perfect and if not then I can explain some parts in the comments too. Let me know :)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer. I've just tried the code and it doesn't seem to give as output the strings that the user gives us in input. Those are "cognome, nome, comune di residenza, etc.". Let me know, thanks!

Comment: I tried to show input in a much cleaner way but forgot that you are a complete newbie. You want the output to be a string. I made a pen here https://codepen.io/HARSH_VATS/pen/ExWPXJb